Close ends / caps on screw-modifier. Manifold?
I use a “screw” modifier, which works quite well. But the ends of the spiral always remain open. As a result, neither Boolean works without problems, nor can I export the model for 3D printing.
There is no "cap ends" option?
I am currently working around by additional plates at both ends. This makes 3D printing work reasonably well, but not in complex boolens operations. And I don't want to apply the modifier, because I want to keep the height and spiral number dynamic, editable.
How can I close the ends?

Hello, I think this should be doable with Geometry Nodes. You can look up https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272326/how-can-the-screw-modifier-be-implemented-using-geometry-nodes

Is there some reason you didn't just edit your already asked question about this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/326092/close-endcaps-at-screw-modifier

Sorry, I didnt find my yesterdays post. I thought I missed sending it.
I will close double post!

Oh wow, I missed that quellenform's replica, quite impressive.

If the hole can be filled with n-gon, you can add a geonodes setup like this:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

It assumes non-manifold mesh boundaries are the beginning and end. It works for most cases including yours (especially as you aim for manifold), but will fail if the base geometry isn't a closed loop.
Half of the points of separated beginning/end is the number of vertices of an n-gon cap to generate.
Duplicate the cap, as we need two.
Convert open caps to curves to sort their indices.
Now because the "Mesh Circle" generates indices in winding order, and "Duplicate Elements" keeps the same order, adding it after original, the indices match with these of the curves, so just map position by index.
Merge with the base. This will fail for some scenarios where screw overlaps self. You can remedy this by using selection and selecting both new closed caps and old open caps and nothing else. You will need to merge in two steps if you want to support caps overlapping.

If you want to support more complex caps, it's not hopeless, but you would need to use convex hull on both open caps separately, pick the biggest face for each, use its normal to rotate the cap to horizontal, move to z=0, fill curve, move back to original z, invert rotation.
Update: I realized one of the caps will have a wrong normal, as there's nothing in the mesh to curve conversion that would guarantee counter-clockwise (as seen from outside of the screw) winding order. So I mark the caps with boolean selection, then merge with the rest of the screw, then grow that selection to contain one segment to gain thickness for convex hull (which has to be applied for both ends separately, hence using instances, but "Separate Geometry"→2×"Convex Hull"→"Join Geometry" would work too) then I compare the normal of the caps with the normal of the convex hull to decide if it matches or should be flipped:

Imgur Mirror
